# Rationalisation of different implementations that are in fact very similar

Tags: delphi

I have several functions like this one :

```
TStringListSortCompare = function(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;

procedure TStringList.QuickSort(L, R: Integer; SCompare: TStringListSortCompare);
begin
  ..
  SCompare(Self, I, P);
  ... 
end;
```

or

```
TMyStringListSortCompare = function(List: TMyStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;

procedure TMyStringList.QuickSort(L, R: Integer; SCompare: TMyStringListSortCompare);
begin
  ..
  SCompare(Self, I, P);
  ... 
end;
```

etc...

All those quicksort implementations are **exactly the same**. Only the param SCompare is different (ex: `TStringListSortCompare = function(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;` for the **TStringList** or `TMyStringListSortCompare = function(List: TMyStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;` for the **TMyStringList**. Because of this SCompare params I have plenty of copy/past QuickSort function in my code and If I need to update one I need copy past the modification in all functions (the same in the delphi source code for exemple, look TStringList.quicksort and TwideStringList.quicksort).

I m looking for a "trick" to make my QuickSort function a global function and make that all `TStringList.QuickSort`, `TMyStringList.QuickSort`, etc. will call this global QuickSort function (or inherit).

I don't think it's possible without sacrificing the simplicity and the speed but I prefer to ask in case I miss something.

Note: Everything start from reading this bug report : https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19551

Comment: Have you tried using generics?

Comment: Impossible to answer with knowing anything about the collection types

Comment: Does TMyStringList inherit from TStringList? If it does, TMyStringList.QuickSort can use the same comparer (The one making use of TStringList).

Comment: @fpiette yes it's inherit from TStringList, I will look now How I can refactor a little now my code, thank !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the classes have the same ancestor (`TStringList`) you can use the base class to compare.

Otherwise you can use generic like that, and do different implementation :

```
TCustomQuickSort<T> = class
  class function Sort(L, R: integer): integer;
end;
```

And call it :

```
TCustomQuickSort<TMyStringListSortCompare>.Sort(i, j);
```

To keep your code close to modification but open to expand, you can use a Factory design pattern to get the sort object you need. If tomorrow you have a `TSuperListSortCompare` you just have to add it.

You can too use interface, by replacing your `SCompare` by the type `ISortableObject` and then you can call your custom `Sort` method.

Comment: I like the interface approach ! and I think it's the best as I do not need to refactor all my code! I will look if it's not costly regarding speed but it's look very promising !